# How do I tell GWT to not compile a permutation for gears

Tags: gwt, geolocation

I have included gwt-html5-geolocation into my GWT project and was disappointed to find that it doubled up on my number of permutations compiled. Apparently if the browser does not support geolocation API then it falls back to use gears to find out your location. Is there a way to NOT compile a permutation for gears similar to the way you can tell GWT to only compile certain browser permutations? (the geolocation stuff is very much a nice-to-have and frankly if the client is running an old browser then I am happy not to get their location)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [`Html5Geolocation.gwt.xml`](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/source/browse/trunk/gwt-mobile-webkit/geolocation/geolocation/src/com/google/code/gwt/geolocation/Html5Geolocation.gwt.xml), you could add

```
<inherits name="com.google.code.gwt.geolocation.Html5Geolocation" />
<set-property name="geolocation.api" value="html5" />
```

which would completely disable the `gears` property value.